# For loop to create multiple ggplots

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I have a data set that has the variables week, socioeconomic status (from 1-5) and number of unique households for each week and each socioeconomic status.

Now, I want to create 5 ggplots, one plot for each socioeconomic status. Each plot should show the development of the number of unique households for one socioeconomic status over several weeks.

I thought about using a for loop but so far I couldn't find a solution that works. Would be great if someone could help me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your data is `df` and you have columns `week`, `ses`, and `nhh`. If you just want to visualize the plot by ses, you can use `facet_wrap()`, like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(week, nhh)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ses)
```

If you would like a dataframe of plots, you can do this:

```
plots <- df %>% 
  group_by(ses) %>%
  summarize(plot = list(ggplot(NULL, aes(week, nhh)) + geom_point()))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
    ses plot  
  <int> <list>
1     1 <gg>  
2     2 <gg>  
3     3 <gg>  
4     4 <gg>  
5     5 <gg>
```

If you would like a list of plot objects, you can do this

```
plots <- lapply(unique(df$ses), \(s) ggplot(df %>% filter(ses == s), aes(week,nhh)) + geom_point())
names(plots = unique(df$ses))
```